# DJI SDK 3.3 - Create multiple threads

Tags: c++, pthreads, dji-sdk

I want to create threads using the DJI OSDK 3.3. I located the definition of PosixThread in the file `posix_thread.cpp`, but since I am rather new to C++, could anyone provide me with some hints/links on how to properly create a custom thread ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions that show some effort to solve the issue tend to receive a better response here.  You should read this article before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not gated to use the posix thread apis.
You can easily use the [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Here is a small runloop-style sample.

```
void
RunLoop::start()
{
  this->asyncThread = std::thread(&RunLoop::asyncStart, this);
}

void
RunLoop::asyncStart()
{
  while (this->shouldRun)
  {
    // Timer's executions
    this->evaluateTimers();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
  }
}
```